# Show URL of a link in Gnus

Tags: gnus

Messages displayed by Gnus with HTML rendering may contain links which don't display the URL, instead they display the text which tells what this link is about.

I've found a way to extract the URL by doing <kbd>M-x</kbd>`describe-text-properties` and then in the buffer with the properties, I'd need to expand the `shr-url` section.  The question thus: is there a more straight-forward way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the cursor over the link, and press "u". This calls `shr-copy-url`, and copies the url into the `kill-ring`. You can paste it then in any browser.